# How to format Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DatePicker to dd-MM-yyyy in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, date-formatting, windows-10-universal

I currently have a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DatePicker that defaults to the American date notation of MM-dd-yyyy. I'd like to change that to dd-MM-yyyy, but I cannot find how to do it with this particular DatePicker. I've seen questions and answers here on SO that use a DatePicker but unfortunately it's not the same DatePicker.

My xaml:

```
<DatePicker Date="{Binding someDate, Converter="{StaticResource DateTimeToDateConverter}", Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The converter:

```
public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo language)
{
  DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
  return date;
}
```

I've tried adding the language parameter to the DatePicker, but it is NOT affected at all... I also change the system setting language from en-US to nl-NL, that also didn't work. Does anyone know what I should do make the DatePicker format to dd-MM-yyyy?

EDIT: The date comes in the right format from the converter, but the actual visual XAML object is MM-dd-yyyy.

Comment: Use StringFormat='dd MMM yyyy'

Comment: Where? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Please read [if questions should include tags in their titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/247579). You have already properly tagged your question, there is no need to put it in the title. There is also no need to put long namespace, as once the question has longer name it becomes harder to read and IMHO gets smaller audience.

Comment: Removed the tags, but the namespace is needed to specific, since there is another DatePicker that does NOT work like this one, and I could only find answers for that other DatePicker. Even answers on this question were refering to the other one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried : return date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy); instead of only return date; ?

EDIT : What you want it invert the column day and on month of the DatePicker. To do this, you have to modify the Template of your control. 
Right click on your DatePicker, Edit Template, Edit a copy. Then just invert the DayTextBlock and the MonthTextBlock in the Template generated.

Comment: I did and as I said in the edit of the question, the converter returns the right formatted date, but the actual XAML object shows the wrong format.

Comment: Ok, I just checked what was the new datePicker. So if I'm not wrong, what you want is invert the column day and month ? For this, you have to modify the Template of your control. Right click on your DatePicker, Edit Template, Edit a copy. Then in the FlyoutButton, just invert the DayTextBlock and the MonthTextBlock.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want so I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: So I did what you suggested, but I couldn't find a flyoutbutton, but I did find the DayTextBlock and MonthTextBlock which were already in the order right, but when run they were inverted so I inverted them in the code, and they showed up in the right format, so it's fixed now. But it's still odd why and where it's being inverted.

Comment: If you change add your comment to your answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: Done :) About the FlyoutButton, I think It depends on the Template and the SDK, it's not Something important :)

Comment: One comment though, the month column still shows the name of the month in English, how do I change that to Dutch?

Comment: For the language, you can add it directly in the DatePicker control : <DatePicker Language="nl-NL" />

Comment: That's weird, it's also not working for me. Does your app have to be only in Dutch ? It works if you change directly the Default Language of your App in the Package.appxmanifest > Application.

Comment: I'll try that and the app is currently in both Dutch and English.

Comment: I changed the default language in the Package.appxmanifest, but it didn't change anything unfortunately. :(

Comment: I have inverted month and day position in the template  but nothing changed. Really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for set required date time format.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
 <Setter Property="Control.Template">
  <Setter.Value>
   <ControlTemplate>
    <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
     Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd MMM yyyy', 
     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
   </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: It gives an syntax error that it does not recognise StringFormat as a parameter of Binding and it also does not recognise x:Type as TargetType.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DatePicker and not the old one?

Comment: Not sure, but StringFormat cannot be use in UWP apps (Win10, Win8, WP8...).